# Waiting for CloudFlare DDOS Protection LWP Perl

Tags: regex, perl, cloudflare, lwp, lwp-useragent

Edit: Ended up using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox. I answered my own question below.

I am trying to access a website and download it's page. The cloudflare DDOS protection on the site will occasionally come on, and I can't make LWP go through it. I can successfully detect that a page *is* a cloudflare splash page with the regex `/Ray ID: [a-f0-9]*/` but whenever I attempt to connect again I just get the same splash screen with a new Ray ID. Here is a (condensed) code sample:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.3.0');
$signin_url = 'my url';
$signin_page = $ua->get($signin_url);
if($signin_page->content =~ /Ray ID: ([a-f0-9]*)/i) {
     print "DDOS protection page here\n";
     #more code to retry, but just gets back into this part of the IF
 } else {
     print "Not the DDOS page\n";
     #now I would save to file
}
```

Since that doesn't work I need to be able to do it another way.

Comment: I see no question here.

Comment: The question was 'How does one access a site with cloudflare protection using LWP' @DaveSherohman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare needed Javascript, so I used WWW::Mechanize::Firefox. Like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
system('firefox &'); #The & makes it so the program doesn't wait.
sleep 5; #So firefox can load
$mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new;
$mech->get('http://www.mycloudflareblockedwebsite.com/');
if($mech->content =~ /Test if it is the CLOUDFLARE source HTML page/) {
      sleep 10; #Wait for cloudflare to do it's thing
}
```

Taa daa!

It took me a long time to do that.

Answer (score 5):

The DDOS protection intercepts the request, sets a cookie and then redirects you to the target page. You have to submit the cookie you got from the interception on the next request to get through the DDOS protection. [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) will do this for you if you create a cookie jar.

```
LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => {} )
```

[WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize), a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, passes that argument to LWP::UserAgent for you, so you can also use

```
 use WWW::Mechanize;
 my $ua = WWW::Mechanize->new;
```

When the `LWP::UserAgent` or `WWW::Mechanize` UA has a cookie jar, `get` will automatically accept the cookie, follow the redirection, and submit the cookie in the subsequent requests.

Comment: LWP can do it just fine, if `cookie_jar` is set to an `HTTP::Cookies` object. All Mech does is set one up by default, while LWP leaves it up to the user.

Comment: In fact `$ua->cookie_jar({});` is enough to instantiate an in-memory cookie jar that will do the job.